# Object Reference Not set to instance of an object error while using FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#

When I use this below code, I get object reference error, this might be because there is no match for "spider". My question is, How to check for null value in these situations

```
int fooID = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Bar == "spider").ID;
```

I'm using this same scenario for different conditions for fetching different Items from the list like

```
int fooID = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Bar == "spider").ID; 
String fooDescription = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Sides == "Cake").Description;
```

Is there any other way to check for null values.

Comment: Also noteworthy: checking whether `foos` is `null` or not (unless you're absolutely certain it cannot be `null`)

Comment: It's also important to know that `null` is not the only value you may get back from `FirstOrDefault`, it depends on the type you are working with. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Also sometime it's usefull to get 0 (default int value) if query contains 0 elements. It may be done like so:
`int fooID = foos.Where(f => f.Bar == "spider").Select(f => f.ID).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I would go with @Ilya's answer.  This is the only sure fire way to avoid the NRE without following @ Trevor's answer, which, I might add, would actually be my preferred method!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same way as you normally would, assign a variable and check it.

```
var foo = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Bar == "spider");

if (foo != null)
{
    int fooID = foo.ID;
}
```

Based upon your updated example, you would need to do this instead:

```
var fooForId = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Bar == "spider");
var fooForDescription = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Sides == "Cake");

int fooId = fooForId != null ? fooForId.Id : 0;
string fooDescription = fooForDescription != null ? fooForDescription.Description : null; // or string.Empty or whatever you would want to use if there is no matching description.
```

Comment: Thanks!!..But I'm using this same scenario for different conditions for fetching different Items from the list like     

int fooID = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Bar == "spider").ID;                                 String fooDescription = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Sides == "Cake").Description;    

Is there any other way to check for null values.

Comment: @Mohan then you should update your example so we have half a chance of understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method for bevaiour if there is no matching elements. Next code demonstrates the usage

```
string[] foos = {"tyto", "bar"};

var res = foos.Where(s => s.Length == 2)
              .DefaultIfEmpty("default")
              .First()
              .Length;

Console.WriteLine (res); //will print the length of default, which is 7
```